# Spring Security: The routes are not protected

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to do a simple example with Spring Security to handle authentication and authorization to a simple web app.

To do this, I put the Spring Security dependency in the project's pom.xml file.

Then I created three simple html pages: admin.html, home.html, login.html.

They are these:

admin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:sec="https://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6">
<head>
<title>Administrator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:inline="text">Welcome administrator [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<p>Click <a th:href="@{/admin}">here</a> to access protected area</p>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
You have been logged out.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
<div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
<div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
<div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I created the following configuration classes:
AppAuthConfig.java

```
package com.ap.springsecuritydemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class AppAuthConfig{
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.permitAll()
.and()
.logout()
.permitAll();

return http.build();
}

@Bean
public InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
.username("pinco")
.password("pallo")
.roles("USER")
.build();
return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.ap.springsecuritydemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName("admin");
}
}
```

And in addition the following controller:

```
package com.ap.springsecuritydemo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
@RequestMapping("login")
public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
return "home";
}

@RequestMapping("admin")
public ModelAndView showEditProductForm(){
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("admin");

return mav;
}
}
```

The problem is: already by inserting the Spring Security dependency I should have route protection. However, this does not happen in my case. Why?

The problem is: already by inserting the Spring Security dependency I should have route protection. However, this does not happen in my case. Why?

Comment: You need `@EnableWebMvc`. There is no automatic protection unless you are using Spring Boot.